# yii2 populate grid with record from another table

Tags: php, grid, left-join, yii2

I am trying to show fields from another model in grid but I can't get it working.

I have 2 tables: *Customers* and *Attendance* and I need to bring only today's attendance for each customer.

From attendance I am trying to get the field attendance.doctor

In the grid I am trying to get a function but is not working.

```
$gridColumns = [
    [
        'label' => 'Doctor',
        'value' => function ($model, $index, $dataColumn) {
            return $model->attendance->doctor;
        },
    ],

    ...
];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took me some hours but I find the way probably not the best but works.

in the view I am using the kartik grid but works the same with the default grid.

I have 3 fields that i want to get from the Attendance table (Dropin, Doctor and Lawyer).

```
        [
    'class' => 'kartik\grid\BooleanColumn',
    'vAlign' => 'middle',
    'label' => 'Dropin',
    'value' => function($model, $index, $dataColumn) {
                    return $model->getAttendances('Dropin');
                },
    ],                            
    [
    'class' => 'kartik\grid\BooleanColumn',
    'vAlign' => 'middle',
    'label' => 'Doctor',
    'value' => function($model, $index, $dataColumn) {
                    return $model->getAttendances('Doctor');
                },
    ],                            
    [
    'class' => 'kartik\grid\BooleanColumn',
    'vAlign' => 'middle',
    'label' => 'Lawyer',
    'value' => function($model, $index, $dataColumn) {
                    return $model->getAttendances('Lawyer');
                },
    ],
```

The getAttendences function it is defined in the current model (Customers)

```
    public function getAttendances($field_to_search)
{       
    $model =  Attendance::find()->where(['CustomersID'=>$this->ID])->one();
    if (! empty($model)) {
       //design my GridView
        $value = $model->$field_to_search;
    }
    else
    {
        $value = 0;
    }
    return $value;
}
```

I am publishing the project at:

https://github.com/open-ecommerce/oe-dropin

In case you want to have a look of even better help.....

(It is a free simple project I am helping to develop for a charity)

Answer (score 0):

The closure for "value" is :

```
function($model, $key, $index, $widget) {
  return $model->attendance->doctor->name;
}
```

Or you can do this :

```
"value" => "attendance.doctor.name"
```

Doc : http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-data-widgets.html#column-classes

Comment: Thanks timothee.  Doctor is a boolean field not the table just to know if goes the doctor. Name dosn't exist.  the table is attendance and the field doctor.  but the active model is customers and I don't know how to get it from another model (attendance)

Comment: Did you use Gii for generating CRUD ? It creates relations on models.
I don't understand what you don't know

Comment: Looks like i miss the relation on models.  what i did is use Gii to create the crud for the 2 separate tables customers and attendance I didn't know that it is possible to do the relation between tables with Gii